simulateContract vs prepareContract, and the purpose of these?
I just want to check my understanding of the purpose of the two:

simulateContract, is the purpose of this, is to check whether or not the transaction would go through? And the reason we would want to check, is to not have a failed transaction use up gas unnecessarily ?

prepareContract, I'm a bit lost for this one. Because I don't HAVE to actually pass information into prepareContract, I can just pass it directly to writeContract, and do the transaction. What's the purpose of prepareContract ?



I believe prepareContract is now deprecated.

In wagmi 2.x, prepareContract is deprecated.
Instead of use simulateContract.
Pairing simulateContract with writeContract allows you to validate if the transaction will succeed ahead of time. If the simulate succeeds, writeContract can execute the transaction.
